Origem do Termo "Grogue" utilizado na ilha madeira e em cabo verde
Origem do Termo "Grogue" utilizado na ilha madeira e em cabo verde
Ouvi muito na madeira e agora também em cabo verde

Todos os dicionários que eu conheço dão o mesmo origem, grog no inglês (apesar do termo inglês referir a uma outra bebida)

Está no Priberam: https://dicionario.priberam.org/grogue#google_vignette A origem é o inglês, grog.

Uma palavra inglesa. Possivelmente por terem existido muitos ingleses no desenvolvimento da  Madeira? será ?! Penso que o normal seria chamar aguardente em Portugal

É a primeira vez que encontro "grogue" como substantivo.

@stafusa e para mim, como adjectivo: em Cabo Verde só o ouvi como substantivo. O adjectivo é originalmente derivado dum substantivo, agora, fiquei curioso se o adjectivo em português veio do substantivo português, ou do inglês groggy.

@ClMend houve ingleses na história de Madeira e de Cabo Verde sim, mas eu não sei se é por isso a palavra. Ambos o Portugal e a Inglaterra foram poderes marítimos, e estamos falando de ilhas.
